# Can I hide the share link/button in SharePoint 2013 Foundation?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I see the "Share" button in the ribbon and the link in the context menu. Can I hide it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide it using CSS:

```
//Promoted Action button, List View Quick Control Button, ECB/Callout 
a[id$="site_share_button"], button.js-listview-qcbShareButton, a.ms-calloutLink[title="Share"] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Go to Settings > Site Settings > Site Permissions > Access Request Settings > And uncheck that option. Now only Admins should be able to see it.

But just a heads-up, the share button is there so a user can send a request to let another employee have access to the site, and the request must be validated by an admin/owner.

( I removed my username, it's still there. )

[image: Standard user]

Comment: I did this. It is not working.

Comment: Are you still logged in as a owner or administrator? Try logging in as a standard user with edit/contribute/view permission. It worked straight away for me.

Answer (score 0):

We did it a bit differently. For us we wanted to block sharing on the MySites to prevent internal data leaks.

If a user tries to share from their personal page they will get the following error - "Sorry, something went wrong. Only a limited set of people are allowed to share this content."

CSS hacks were not required for this as there is a feature that can be disabled in the central admin page.

Central Admin > Manage Web Applications > Highlight your SharePoint - Mysites site > User Permissions

**Uncheck** *Manage Permissions - Create and change permission levels on the Web site and assign permissions to users and groups.*

This will prevent the users from being able to adjust the permissions themselves for files/folders on their MySite.